# Get the days, hours and minutes in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So This is my first time using Moment.js and I encountered the following problem, so I have this following dates:

```
now: 2017-01-26T14:21:22+0000
expiration: 2017-01-29T17:24:22+0000
```

What I want to get is:

```
Day: 3
Hours: 3
Mins: 3
```

I tried the following code:

```
const now = moment();
const exp = moment(expire_date);
console.log(expire_date);
days = exp.diff(now, 'days');
hours = exp.diff(now, 'hours') - (days * 24);
minutes = exp.diff(now, 'minutes') - ((days * 1440) + (hours * 24) * 60);
```

I know I did something wrong (maybe my calculation or I used the wrong method), but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

MomentJS can calculate all that for you without you doing any logic.

- First find the difference between the two moments
- Express it as a Duration
- Then display whichever component `.days()`, `.hours()` of the duration that you want.

Note: You can also express the entire duration `.asDays()`, `.asHours()` etc if you want.

```js
const now = moment("2017-01-26T14:21:22+0000");
const expiration = moment("2017-01-29T17:24:22+0000");

// get the difference between the moments
const diff = expiration.diff(now);

//express as a duration
const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);

// display
console.log("Days:", diffDuration.days());
console.log("Hours:", diffDuration.hours());
console.log("Minutes:", diffDuration.minutes());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution will not show the correct number of days if the interval is greater than a month. Use this for days: `console.log("Days:", expiration.diff(now, "days"));`

Answer (score 4):

this will give you the right values and remove the headache of manual calculations

```js
let expiration = "2017-01-29T17:24:22+0000"
const now = moment();
const exp = moment(expiration);

console.log(exp.format());

days = exp.diff(now, 'days');
hours = exp.subtract(days, 'days').diff(now, 'hours');
minutes = exp.subtract(hours, 'hours').diff(now, 'minutes');

console.log(days, hours, minutes)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

note that the `substract` operations will mutate the original `exp` value, so don't go passing it around expecting it to be the original date

Answer (score 1):

Try my solution. I think that is it:

```
  var now = moment("2017-01-26T14:21:22+0000");
  var expiration = moment("2017-01-29T17:24:22+0000");
  var minsAverage = expiration.diff(now, "minutes");

  var min = parseInt(minsAverage % 60);
  var hours = parseInt(minsAverage / 60);
  var days = parseInt(hours / 24);
  hours = hours - 24*days;
```

Answer (score 0):

For more information check the documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```js
var now = moment()
var exp = moment().add(1,'days')
var days = exp.diff(now, 'days')
var months = exp.diff(now, 'months')
var years = exp.diff(now, 'years', true) //float number

console.log(now,exp,days, months, years)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```