# Calculate the difference between two dates in javascript using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to get the difference between two date in react whith two datepicker and two timepicker ( a react component ). The date is for a booking and I want to get the duration by substract the "end date" with "start date", but when I subtract two date whith more than 24 hours I have a -152 or a value that not corresponding to the real duration.

The code

```
periodReserve = (e, idPark, title ) => {
let Start_Day = this.state.startDate && this.state.startDate.format(Formatdate);
let Start_Hour = this.state.time && this.state.time.format(formatHour);
let End_Day = this.state.endDate && this.state.endDate.format(Formatdate);
let End_Hour = this.state.timeEnd && this.state.timeEnd.format(formatHour);
let diff = this.state.timeEnd - this.state.startDate;
console.log(diff);}
```

[image: The error]

The code for the first DatePicker and the TimePicker ( for the start )

```
<DatePicker
  id="calendar"
  className="TestIcon"
  dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
  placeholderText="Date de fin"
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChangeStart}/>

<TimePicker showSecond={false}
     placeholder={time}
     onChange={this.onChangeStart}> </TimePicker>
```

The code for the second dataPicker and TimePicker

```
<DatePicker
    id="calendar"
    className="TestIcon"
    dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
    selected={this.state.endDate}
    onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}/>

 <TimePicker showSecond={false}
  placeholder={timeEnd}
  onChange={this.onChangeEnd}> </TimePicker>
```

Comment: Save yourself some headache and use `momentjs`
Sample code calculating duration https://stackoverflow.com/a/41876250/184646

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sample code using [momentJS](https://momentjs.com)

```js
this.state = {startDate:1519026163000, timeEnd:1519126755000} // example

const startDate = moment(this.state.startDate);
const timeEnd = moment(this.state.timeEnd);
const diff = timeEnd.diff(startDate);
const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);

console.log("Total Duration in millis:", diffDuration.asMilliseconds());
console.log("Days:", diffDuration.days());
console.log("Hours:", diffDuration.hours());
console.log("Minutes:", diffDuration.minutes());
console.log("Seconds:", diffDuration.seconds());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank's it's exactly what I need !!

Answer (score 4):

```
  const dateConverter = (startDate, timeEnd) => {
    const newStartDate= new Date(startDate);
    const newEndDate=new Date(timeEnd);
    const one_day = 1000*60*60*24;
    let result
    result = Math.ceil((newEndDate.getTime()-newStartDate.getTime())/(one_day))
    console.log('date Converter result', result)
    if (result < 0 ) {return 0}
    return result
  }
```

Result in Days

Answer (score 0):

**it is small libaray**

[click for reference](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/moment-js-moment-diff-function/amp/)

*`npm i moment`*

```
  const dateConverter = (startDate, timeEnd) => {
     const newStartDate= new Date(startDate);
     const newEndDate=new Date(timeEnd);
     let result=moment(newStartDate).diff(newEndDate,'days')
     return result   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Quick remark to the snippet

If you want absolute values like 250 days.
You should use this:

```
diffDuration.asDays()
```